# typeorm relation in embedded column

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I'm working with NestJs, Typeorm and Postgresql.

I'm trying to use ManyToOne relation in embedded entity. I need to load foreign key column in node environment, so added one additional column(createdById column below). This makes problem.

Here is my code.

**A.ts**

```js
@Entity()
export class A {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column(() => Embed, { prefix: false })
    embed!: Embed;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
    createdAt!: Date;
}
```

**Embed.ts**

```js
export class Embed {
    @Column()
    x!: number;

    @Column()
    y!: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => B)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'created_by_id' })
    createdBy?: B;

    @Column({ name: 'created_by_id' })
    createdById!: number;
}
```

**B.ts**

```js
@Entity()
export class B {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at' })
    createdAt!: Date;
}
```

When I run the app with option `TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE=true` and `TYPEORM_LOGGING=true`, I get error messages like `query failed: CREATE TABLE "a" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "created_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(), "created_by_id" integer NOT NULL, "created_by_id" integer NOT NULL, "x" integer NOT NULL, "y" integer NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_684f21444e543375e4c2e6f27fe" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`, `Message: column \"created_by_id\" specified more than once.`. Typeorm trying to create `created_by_id` column twice. (I applied custom NamingStrategy so that column of embedded entity's name to be snake_case)

If I place `createdBy` and `createdById` column to `A` directly, then it makes no error. Is it problem of typeorm version? Or any other solutions?

package version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "7.1.0,
    "typeorm": "0.2.31",
}
```

run with docker container,

```
node image: 16.14.2-alpine3.15,
postgres image: mdillon/postgis:11-alpine
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeORM docs say you don't need to decorate embed class with `@Entity()`.

See `Name` class in https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/embedded-entities

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually, I didn't put @Entity() decorator on the Embed class. I would edit the question,,